# Error object in the client side not showing the error message

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, redux

I am a begginer in developing full stack applications. I'm currently building a React, Node and Express.js application where users login. I have error checking in the backend side and I want to show it on the client side.

here's my Node Code:

```
app.post("/api/login",async(req,res)=>{
  try {
    const { email, password } = req.body;
      const user = await User.findOne({ email });
      if (!user) {
        return res.status(404).send({ message: "No user with that email" });
      }
      const isMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
      if (!isMatch) {
        return res.status(401).send({ message: "Passwords do not match" });
      }
      res.send(user);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).send(error);
    
  }
})
```

I'm using redux actions to make the request
here's my React Code:

```
export const logIn = credentials => async dispatch => {
  try {
    const res = await axios.post("/api/login", credentials);
    console.log(res.data);
    dispatch({
      type: LOG_IN,
      payload: res.data
    });
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({ type: LOG_IN_FAILED });
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

When I console.log the error.message, I'm getting `Request failed with status code 404` Instead of the error message e.g `{ message: "No user with that email" }`.But when I make the request with postman, I'm getting the error message `{ message: "No user with that email" }`.Is there a way I can show that on my client side? Because `error.message` doesnot seem to work

Comment: The message is still present in `error` object. Try with `console.log(error.message)`

Comment: @SagarChilukuri when I ```console.log(error)``` I'm getting ```Error: Request failed with status code 404
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at settle (settle.js:17)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:61)``` and when I ```console.log(error.message)``` I get ```Request failed with status code 404```

Comment: Change from `console.log(error)` to `console.log(error.message)`

Comment: when I ```console.log(error.message)``` I get ```Request failed with status code 404```

Comment: Did you check "Network Tab" in your browser devtools if you hit the correct address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error object on the `error.response.data` which contained the actual error from my backend which was `{ message: "No user with that email" }` so the code would look like this:

```
export const logIn = credentials => async dispatch => {
  try {
//make request to backend (with axios in my case)
 } catch ({reponse}) {
    dispatch({ type: LOG_IN_FAILED });
    console.log(response.data); //find the error object from the backend incase of an error
  }
};
```

For more info, check out https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/960